# How to show ProgressMonitorDialog along with Progress in Status Line

Tags: java, eclipse, jface

On click of OK button of my JFace dialog i'm displaying the progress in the Progress indicator section of status line in the following way :

```
class MyJob extends Job
{
    MyJob()
    {
        super("Job name");
    }

    public IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) 
    {
        monitor.beginTask("Job", workCount);
        try
        {
            //customCode();
        }
        finally
        {
            monitor.done();
        }
        return Status.OK_STATUS;
    }
 }
```

Along with this user needs to be displayed with
org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.

Where do I initiate this dialog from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `Job.setUser(true)` before the job is scheduled. This will cause a progress dialog to be shown.

Comment: when i initiate a MessageDialog afer monitor.beginTask() i  get an invalid thread exception, any other way or place to display a message box ?

Comment: Use `Display.getDefault().asyncExec(runnable)` to run code in the UI thread, but displaying a popup from a background thread may annoy the user.